# Why does DataAdapter.Update update nothing?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In the code below I add a row into my DataTable and try to update the database. In result, the element DataTable has the added row, but the table in the database doesn't change.

Would you be so kind to help me with fixing the problem.

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|db.mdf;"
    +"Integrated Security=True";
string command = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, connstr);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
var ds = new DataSet();
try
{
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    DataTable tab = ds.Tables[0];

    var r = tab.NewRow();
    r["name"] = "TestName";
    r["length"] = 1;
    r["Comment"] = "SomeComment";
    tab.Rows.Add(r);              

    adapter.Update(tab);
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

Console.Read();
```

Instead of adapter.Update(tab) I also tried adapter.Update(ds), but there was nothing new.

Here is my Table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhWFO.png

INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands are provided by SqlCommandBuilder in my code. To check ones' correctness, I called builder's properties:

```
builder.GetInsertCommand().CommandText;
builder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText;
builder.GetDeleteCommand().CommandText;
```

There were values

```
INSERT INTO [myTable] ([name], [length], [comment]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)
UPDATE [myTable] SET [name] = @p1, [length] = @p2, [comment] = @p3 WHERE (([Id] = @p4) AND     ([name] = @p5) AND ([length] = @p6) AND ((@p7 = 1 AND [comment] IS NULL) OR ([comment] = @p8)))
DELETE FROM [myTable] WHERE (([Id] = @p1) AND ([name] = @p2) AND ([length] = @p3) AND ((@p4 = 1 AND [comment] IS NULL) OR ([comment] = @p5)))
```

As fas as I understand, in my case the query INSERT takes place. In my oppinion, there is all right with it.

As for primary key, there is one in my table.

Comment: I think you should set `UpdateCommand` property before calling `Update`

Comment: How do you check that your record has not been inserted?

Comment: do you get any exception?

Comment: Commands INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE are defined by SqlCommandBuilder as shown in the last code snippet. As I understand, in my case the line adapter.Update calls the query INSERT, because there is just adding a row to existing table. It seems to have clear and proper form.

Comment: Do you have you MDF file listed between your project files? If yes what is its property Copy To Output Directory?

Comment: There were no exceptions. To check changes, I both created new SELECT queries and seen the table view in Visual Studio Constructor.

Comment: I have MDF file attached to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common scenario. You have your database file listed between your project items and it has the property `Copy To output Directory` set to `Copy Always`.
This means that every time you start a debug session, the Visual Studio copies your MDF file from the project location to the BIN\DEBUG folder (or x86 and RELEASE variations) overwriting the file present there.
Of course this copy doesn't have the newest record added in the previous run.

So your code is working correctly but the configuration of your project wreak havoc with your checks

Simply change your property to `Do Not Copy` or `Copy if Newer`